# In what format does the argument to the predict method have to be in? The data in my x_training are lists so I don't why list didn't work

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

https://github.com/olaniyigeorge/makeodds/blob/main/fmodel.py

In what format does the argument to the predict method have to be in? The data in my `x_training` are lists so I don't why list didn't work. I'm getting

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape 2 but received input with shape [None, 1].

Also the accuracy is all over the place. Getting something like 0.000e+00

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mre].

Comment: Code has to be directly in the question, not as an external link.

Comment: I couldn't get the format right. I'm using a phone atm.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in machine learning the training data needs to be in a multi-dimensioned array (in your case, 2D array) (typically) with number of rows equal to number of samples and number of columns equal to number of features. When you predict, you generally predict only one sample, and it is indeed tempting to simply use a list. However, keras and other libraries like pytorch defaults the first dimension to be the batch size. So you need to make your list an array with

```
shape = [1, #_of_features]
```

for predict to work.